# How to make a REST API for OCR

Tags: python, rest, machine-learning, flask, ocr

I am doing a task in which I have an image and have to extract dates from it. The dates are extracted with Google Cloud Platform Vision API. How can I make API with flask that accepts image and returns date? The format would look something like below:

> Request:POST /extract_date
>
> Payload: {“base_64_image_content”: }
>
> Response: If date is present: {“date”: “YYYY-MM-DD”} If date is not
>   present: {“date”: null}

Can you please help me?

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow, but luckily there are a ton of tutorials about this topic available on the internet.

Comment: @KlausD. I think OP the OP did some research around the subject. I agree that it's relatively broad, but then that's the type of questions often new people ask. I'd not dismiss it

Comment: Following our discussion, I extended the answer with GCP Functions code. You might want to elaborate your question and / or specify that you're interested in OCR REST API on GCP. GCP is helpful here because of negligible cost of Functions, plus no issues with authenticating Vision API that you have to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask) is among the most popular web frameworks for Python. It's relatively easy to learn, while its extension [Flask-RESTful](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) enables you to quickly build REST API.

Minimal example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class MyApi(Resource):
    def get(self, date):
        return {'date': 'if present'}

api.add_resource(MyApi, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Test with `curl`:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/ -d "data=base_64_image_content" -X PUT
```

Following discussion in comments, here's how one can build OCR REST API with [GCP Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/):

```
import re
import json
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
from google.cloud import vision
from flask import Response


def detect_text(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    image = vision.types.Image(content=request.data)
    response = client.text_detection(image=image)
    serialized = MessageToJson(response)
    annotations = json.loads(serialized)

    full_text = annotations['textAnnotations'][0]['description']
    annotations = json.dumps(annotations)

    r = Response(response=annotations, status=200, mimetype="application/json")
    return r
```

Here's piece of code you can use to make the request:

```
def post_image(path, URL):
    headers = {'content-type': 'image/jpeg'}
    img = open(path, 'rb').read()
    response = requests.post(URL, data=img, headers=headers)
    return response
```

Comment: Thanks can you please explain me I am using vision api by google for image to text task and after some preprocessing steps i extract date , so i have a python code file which do this task and now all i want if one use my api it uploads image and then my code runs and dates were extracted. Actually i never build api if i am understanding something wrong correct me

Comment: @EshanAgarwal Running a flask server is then one option. If you're using GCP, then you might consider using GCP Functions, serverless execution environment. Functions behave to large extent like `flask` and body of the functions can be (almost) identical. Functions strip away much of the deployment and scalingcomplexity (replacing them with different problems that are likely not an issue for you). You will likely want to have your local `flask` server for debugging, so the code above is relevant.

Comment: Ok so if I am using GCP then I have to deploy it on GCP ? But then how can i make REST api using gcp.

Comment: You don't, you can deploy whatever, your home PC, Amazon or toaster, as long as it supports the software stack. GCP will just make it easier for you. How to make REST API? I have just given you what you should lookup (GCP Functions). Read tutorials, try deploying something both with Functions and Flask standalone (as I have just described) and then come with more specific questions / issues. Close this question if it gives you guidance on next steps. You won't get more precise answers unless you have more specific questions.

Comment: How can i make requests ?

Comment: @EshanAgarwal With e.g. `curl` (in the answer) or Python (edited answer).

Comment: Actually i have write code using vision api in which i first set up credentials in gcp and download key and perform vision api task and after some preprocessing extract dates. So how can i use it in flask and make rest api as i mentioned above?

Comment: @EshanAgarwal Have you bothered to check what I wrote? I have presented you with two ways (pure flask and GCP Functions) to make the API, what is not clear? That's the moment when you have to roll up your sleeves and try it out, perhaps read more on flask is needed. Again, in the answer you have two working examples on how to make REST API. I can't help you further unless you start working on the problem too. I suggest accept (or not) the answer, try the code, run some tutorials and post new, more concrete question.

Comment: Hey I make rest api and it running well as I want but when i am trying to upload .jpeg file failed to upload it can you suggest some answers

Comment: @EshanAgarwal We can't work indefinitely on a question, it's what one could call a "feature creep". Close this question and ask a new one, with code, errors you get and detailed description. This way you'll get much better response and reverse downvotes trend in your question. I can then try to help you.